# how to execute a php script on page load?

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

I am new to developing an website i've create a php page which prints hello world. I have used iframe tag to link that html file. But whenever browser redirect to that php file the browser ask to download that file rather than displaying hello world can any one tell me whats going wrong here. 
My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="hello.php"></iframe>
Script executed
</body>
</html>
```

I know its very silly question but i searched on so many website didn't got any clue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: your server isn't set up to parse php then...

Comment: i just used google drive to upload files just because it allows you to host your website so i tried that one do i need to use domain or file hosting server??

Comment: you need a hosting platform with php installed, otherwise the php files are just plain old text and wont get interpreted. Try it locally by installing WAMP http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should set up a server , only then can you execute your php scripts . If you're using windows , then use WAMP , else if you're using linux , do sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ on the terminal .. In case of windows , copy paste your files to C:\wamp\www (path may differ general format - Path\to\wamp\www ) . And in case of linux copy/paste them into /var/www

Comment: Ya I executed,the php on wamp n but I don't have any experience of hosting a website, ok I'll try with free hosting website thanx for everyone for helping